# Formally prove that a subset S of R^n, whose members are all isolated, is at most countable

Tags: real-analysis

There was a previous post I saw in May that looks like addressed a slight variation to this question but I'll ask anyway for clarity.

If I have a set $S \subset \Bbb R$ (I will focus on the real line first and then make an argument that the proof holds for all n-space) and every point $p \in S$ is isolated, then how do you prove that S is at most countable? Let me show what I've done so far.

If all points are isolated, then for every $p \in S$, p is not a limit point of S. This means that for each point p, $\exists$ some open ball of p $B_r(p)$ with no $q \neq p$ such that $q \in S$. If S is finite, then it is clearly at most countable, just by the definition.

If S is infinite, we can separate it into its rational and irrational parts. Let I be the set of $p \in S$, where p is irrational. And if I is finite, then I is clearly at most countable. But now assume that I is infinite. Because $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, $\exists$ 2 rational numbers a < b such that $(a, b) \cap S = \{p\}$. So for every 2 rationals a and b, there exists an open set with only p. Because $\Bbb Q$ is countable, I is countable.

Let A be the set $q\in S$, where $q \in \Bbb Q$. If A is finite, it is clearly at most countable. If A is infinite, then it must be countable because the set of $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Therefore, S is at most countable. And if it's at most countable in 1 dimension, then it follows by induction that it's at most countable in n dimensions. Any improvements or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do the proof in $\Bbb R^n$ from the start.  At the end of your third paragraph, don't bother with whether $S$ is finite or infinite.  Just use the balls that you have observed the existence of.

Specifically, shrink all of those balls by a factor of 1/2, so that they do not overlap.  Then for each ball, pick one element of $\Bbb Q^n$ that is inside the ball.

(If you want to make this "picking" concrete, then since $\Bbb Q^n$ is countable, you can use a bijection between $\Bbb Q^n$ and $\Bbb N$ to pick the "first" rational point in the ball.)

This provides an injection from $S$ into the countable set $\Bbb Q^n$, so $S$ must be countable.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your reply. I don't understand your suggestion of shrinking the balls by 1/2 so that they don't overlap, and then pick an element of $\Bbb Q^n$ inside each ball. Each $B_r(p)$ by definition only includes p, so they wouldn't overlap, right? I also don't understand why there must be an element of $\Bbb Q^n$ inside the ball..what if one or more of the coordinates of p were irrational? Then since $B_r(p)$ only contains p, it wouldn't contain any element of $\Bbb Q^n$.

Comment: Since a ball only contains $p$ (of elements of $S$), it will not contain the _center_ of any other ball, but it could still overlap another ball (without there being any element of $S$ in the overlap region).  Shrinking them by 1/2 ensures that they don't touch each other, since then every ball extends less than halfway to any other point of $S$, and so lies strictly within the set of points in $\Bbb R^n$ that are closer to $p$ than to any other point in $S$.

Comment: @Jeff Regarding finding an element of $\Bbb Q^n$ inside the ball, the ball has some size greater than zero, and cannot be empty of elements of $\Bbb Q^n$, because $\Bbb Q^n$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$.  If $p$ is not in $\Bbb Q^n$, it is still a limit point of a sequence of points in $\Bbb Q^n$, and so this sequence must enter the ball.

Comment: OK, I think got it! So each $p \in S$ can therefore be mapped to a unique $y \in \Bbb Q^n$. This is true for 2 reasons. 1) $\Bbb Q^n$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, which means that for each $x \in \Bbb R$, either $x \in \Bbb Q^n$ or there is a member $y \in \Bbb Q^n$ arbitrarily close to x. And 2) each $B_{r/2}(p)$ do not overlap. Letting Y contain all these chosen y, there is a bijection between S and Y. Y is countable, so S is countable.

Comment: @Jeff That's right, the point of your step (1) being that you can always (i.e. for each $p$) choose a $y \in \Bbb Q^n \cap B_{r/2}(p)$, because $\Bbb Q^n \cap B_{r/2}(p)$ cannot be empty, because $\Bbb Q^n$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$.